# Managing ini-files with version control

Tags: git, unix

I am looking for a smart way to manage changes to config files like php.ini and httpd.conf, both changes I make myself and changes that are enforced by version updates of the software they belong to.

Right now, the workflow is like this:

1. Fresh system
2. Edit ini file
3. Install new software version or operating system
4. Manually combine my own ini file with new fresh ini file (boring!)

Wouldn't it be possible to use version control for this? To have a branch for the software developer, and a branch for me, and use merging to elegantly merge their changes with mine, causing conflicts where we have both changed something?

I wonder if anyone could suggest concrete examples of a good way to use git for this. Or other, better ways to do this elegantly.

(I also have a folder called ~/ln/, where i symlink to all the different ini-files I edit in UNIX, since they appear in wildly different places. This way they are also backed up automatically. It would be nice if a version control system could take this into account).

Comment: What an **EXCELLENT** idea! Currently the poor approximation to version control offered by package management systems like debconf is not good enough: either you haven't changed the conf file in which case debconf goes ahead and installs the new one from the package; or else you have, in which case debconf makes you merge/resolve everything manually. To implement this, I think you'd have to publish a standard for everyone to follow, and integrate support for it into tools like debconf.

Comment: By the way, I think git might not be a good fit for this because this really ought to be managed file by file, whereas git has repositories that usually each contain many files. A whole bunch of git repositories each containing a single config file might be a bit unwieldy? Plain RCS might suit better.

Answer (score 0):

I usually track my (user) configuration in a single directory together with a script that can "populate" the home directory - either by creating symlinks or by hard-copying the files to correct places. I don't see what could prevent you from doing the same thing system-wide.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called [etckeeper](http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/) designed to do exactly this.